# bootstrap template & spring boot ( can not display an html page)

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'am using a bootstrap template and spring boot , i wanted to test the controller , for that i code a simple restfull service wich retun  the index page of the template but it didn't work it gives me an error.

Here's the architecture of the project

[image]

And here's my controller

```
package demo.controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import demo.connection.SingletonConnection;
import demo.dao.IDatabase;
import demo.dao.IEntities;
import demo.entities.DB;

@RestController
public class DatabaseController implements ErrorController{
    private static final String PATH = "/error";
    protected Connection conn;
     @Autowired
     private IDatabase db;
     @Autowired 
     private IEntities entities;

    // En cas d'érreur
        @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
        public String error() {
            return "Error";
        }

        @Override
        public String getErrorPath() {
            return PATH;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value="/")
        public String index(Model model){
            return "pages/index.html";
        }    
    }
```

when i run the application with the path : http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: Yuo don't have `@Controller` on `HomeController`. Also why is it an inner class for your error controller? Shouldn't it simply be a toplevel class? Or even beter no class at all? You can simply add a view-controller instead.

Comment: i removed  the class homeController i let juste the @requestMapping ......  . Now when i run the application it doesn't redirect me to the index.html but it displays the string pages /index.html ??

Comment: You didn't understand me correctly and you seem to lack understanding of what an error controller does and what a `@RestController` is. I strongly suggest a read of the Spring reference guide. As I mentioned you should add a [view controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller). Which then again probably breaks as it expects a view name.

Comment: You're right i am new to spring boot and i don 't know how to use a view controller in rest service :/

Comment: You don't you just configure that... As mentioned earlier I suggest a read of the documentation to get an understanding of how things work.

Comment: i read the offcial documentation , i update my post  but it still doesn't work !

Comment: Hi @Hajar, could you solve this problem? Because i have this problem also.